# Bezeichnung für das Empfinden von sexueller Lust und Befriedigung

Tags: single-word-request

Zuerst: Ich bin Deutsch-Muttersprachler. Ich dachte eigentlich bisher, dass hohe `Libido` bedeutet, dass man beim Sex viel Lust bzw. Befriedigung empfindet, weil ich auch dachte, dass `Libido` übersetzt Freude bedeuten würde.

Jetzt habe ich erst heute erfahren und herausgefunden, dass es eher oder auch `sexueller Antrieb` bedeuten kann.

**Meine Frage lautet:**

1. Bezeichnet `Libido` *beides*, also `sexuellen Antrieb` und befriedigendes (hohes) Lustempfinden oder nur das erste?
2. Gibt es ein Pendant bzw. einen ähnlichen Begriff zu `Libido`, der ein (ggf. hohes) Maß an sexueller Lust und Freude während sexueller Aktivität bzw. des Höhepunktes ausdrückt?

Comment: Wieso ist die Antwort mit dem Begriff **Sensualität** weg? Vom Autor oder von einem Moderator gelöscht? Ich fand die Antwort eigentlich ganz gut: Der Begriff Sensualität bezeichnet schließlich den Grad der Empfindsamkeit und so einen ähnlichen bzw. so einen Begriff habe ich ja gesucht. Ich würde mich nur freuen, wenn noch mehr treffende Begriffe kommen würden, die ich noch nicht kenne. Darf ich den Begriff selbst noch mal als Antwort posten?

Comment: Die Antwort zu Sensualität wurde von ihrem Autor @lejonet gelöscht. Keine Ahnung warum.

Comment: Ich würde Lust und Befriedigung nicht gleichsetzen. Lust wird ja eigentlich eher vor dem Akt bis zu einem Höhepunkt erlebt, während Befriedigung vor allem den Zeitraum nach dem Akt betrifft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition des Begriffs **Libido**:

> Bedürfnis sexuelle Lust zu empfinden

(verkürzte Bedeutung im Duden)

Das **Empfinden von Lust während sexueller Aktivität**:

1. Der naheliegende spezifische Begriff

> `sexuelles Lustempfinden`

Bedeutung laut Duden: `Lustgefühl`

2. Weitere Bezeichnung

> `sexuelle Sensitiviät bzw. Sensualität`

ist ein Begriff, der die Fähigkeit, Lust zu empfinden, einer Person beschreibt.

Answer (score 7):

Das lateinische Wort *libido* bedeutet *Begehren, Begierde*. In die deutsche Sprache wurde es durch die Psychoanalyse eingebracht, vor allem durch Siegmund Freud, der mit *Libido* vorrangig (aber nicht nur) die sexuelle Begierde benannte. Sie ist also ein Trieb, der der Arterhaltung dient. Allerdings ging Freud davon aus, dass auch jeder andere lustvolle Trieb letzten Endes aus der Sexualität entsteht.

Davon ausgehend wurde dieser Begriff bald auch mit *Wollust* und *Maßlosigkeit* gleichgesetzt, das sind nicht ganz zufällig die Namen zweier Todsünden im Kontext des Christentums, das Sexualität und Trieben generell ablehnend gegenübersteht.

Die *Libido* ist also das (primär sexuelle) Verlangen, das befriedigt werden will. Sie ist nicht die Empfindung, die man bei der Befriedigung des Triebes hat.

Ein eigener Begriff, der ein starkes Erleben sexueller Reize bezeichnet, ist mir nicht bekannt.

Die Fähigkeit, solche Reize stark zu erleben, würde ich als *Erregbarkeit* bezeichnen. Allerdings hat dieses Wort ein sehr weites Bedeutungsfeld, das die Sexualität nur am Rande mitabdeckt. Und ein synonymes Fremdwort, das mit *Libido* vergleichbar wäre, kenne ich gar nicht.

Comment: Du schreibst: *"wurde dieser Begriff bald auch mit Wollust und **Maßlosigkeit** gleichgesetzt"* - das lese ich auch, immer in dieser Kombination: *Wollust, Trieb, Maßlosigkeit*, aber so ganz klar wird nirgens, wer hier die "Maßlosigkeit" als (Neben-)Bedeutung zu Libido eingeführt haben soll. Die will nämlich überhaupt nicht zur psychoanalytischen Bedeutung passen und wenn Libido im Lateinischen schon diese Bedeutung gehabt hat (was ich erstmal bezweifle), dann wurde das ja nicht neu eingeführt. (Ohne eine gute Referenz würde ich diesen Absatz lieber nicht so stehen lassen)